# C++ Error in program compiling

Tags: c++

Why is this c++ program giving me errors:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (){
    NumbersClass num;       
    num.setNumbers(1);          
}

class NumbersClass
    {
    public:
        NumbersClass() {}           
        void setNumbers(int i) { }          
    };
```

Here are my errors:

```
taskbcplus.cpp(7): error C2065: 'NumbersClass' : undeclared identifier
taskbcplus.cpp(7): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'num'
taskbcplus.cpp(7): error C2065: 'num' : undeclared identifier
taskbcplus.cpp(9): error C2065: 'num' : undeclared identifier
taskbcplus.cpp(9): error C2228: left of '.setNumbers' must have class/struct/union
1>          type is ''unknown-type''
```

Comment: In C++, you at least need a *declaration* before use (this is different than C#, for example).

Comment: @crashmstr In this case, you need the class definition too, since you are instantiating it in `main`.

Comment: @juanchopanza Correct, but you don't need the *implementation* details (i.e. the definitions could be left for *after* main instead of inline with the class).

Comment: @crashmstr Correct. You need the *class definition*, but not the definition of the member functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put the `NumberClass` definition before the point at which you first instantiate it, i.e. before `main`.

```
class NumbersClass
{
public:
    NumbersClass() {}           
    void setNumbers(int i) { }          
};

int main (){
    NumbersClass num;       
    num.setNumbers(1);          
}
```